# Codeigniter: How to repopulate form if using GET query string?

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

CodeIgniter has awesome form validation class that also acts as a way to repopulate the form after submission... provided you use POST.

But how do I repopulate my form after it is submitted, if I use GET query string?

Is there a built-in method to do this, or do I have to write my own class?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user $this->input->get() method to read data from query string (get) and use it after form reloading (this is what you probably mean by 'repopulate').

Example:

```
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $this->input->get('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

For more read:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: you're a genius, thank you! It's so simple, yet I never thought it could be used this way. Btw, here's how I did it in the view file:

<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $this->input->get('username'); ?>" />

Comment: You must enable global_xss_filtering, using `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` to prevent XSS vulnerability. For example, the request `?username=1"><script>alert(/XSS/)</script><input` may create some unwanted element in your page.

Comment: Thanks @ChiChou. Instead of enabling global XSS filter, we could just do $this->input->get('foo', TRUE) so that the GET item is passed thru XSS filter, is that good enough?

Comment: Yes, $this->input->get('foo', TRUE) will take same result as global xss filtering

Answer (score 0):

Also try this.

```
 <input type="text" name="q" placeholder=" Search " value="<?php echo set_value('q',@$_GET['q']); ?>">
```